# Error compiling the io programming language

Tags: python, compilation, iolanguage

I'm trying to compile [io](http://iolanguage.com/) but it's failing and I can't understand why. Here's what I did to compile it:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Here's a gist of [output](https://gist.github.com/1041870) from cmake

Which seems fine but when I run `make` (gist of the [output](https://gist.github.com/1041871))

it fails with something to do with python: `error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."`

I've also tried installing with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.7.

How could I get io to compile (it seems a great language and I'd really like to start using it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your make log then this line could the the *cause*:

> In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/Python.h:57

I don't have that file here (or in my `~/Library/Frameworks/` and Io compiles successfully for me.

So perhaps you are using a different version of Xcode (I'm using 3.2.6 64 bit) or you have installed some Python Xcode *stuff*?  Whatever the difference it looks like the Io build doesn't quite like this (yet).

If you not concerned about having the Python bridge addon then I think you can just delete it (`rm -r io/addons/Python`) and rebuild your source.

Comment: I'm running Xcode 4 and its `/Library/...` not `~/Library/...`

Comment: OK so it possible that the Io has never been tested on Xcode 4 before?  It may only require a little fix in the build code to get it working (I see you've also left a message on the mailing list).